# Force cookbook sync on checkin, Chef

Tags: chef-infra

I've rolled a recipe back to a prior version. Running chef-client doesn't sync the older recipe onto the node. Is there any way to force the node to resync its cookbooks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chef will by default sync the highest version of a cookbook, so you'll need to get rid of the newest cookbook. This can be done using knife (`knife cookbook delete cookbook_to_delete`) or the chef server web ui.

Answer (score 2):

You're advices to use [environments](http://docs.opscode.com/essentials_environments.html) to pin cookbooks to specific versions.

This not only enables you to quiuckly rollback, but also to test changes in a development/preproduction/etc. env.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming, the cookbook name = "apache",  old version = "0.2.0" and latest version = "2.0.1"

If you want specific version of apache cookbook, i.e, 0.2.0 , you may also use below:-

```
chef-client -o recipe[apache@0.2.0]
```